# Parsing html -> xml and querying with Xpath

Tags: c#, .net, xml, html-parsing

I want to parse a html page to get some data.
First, I convert it to XML document using *SgmlReader*.
Then, I load the result to XMLDocument and then navigate through XPath:

```
//contains html document
var loadedFile = LoadWebPage();

...

Sgml.SgmlReader sgmlReader = new Sgml.SgmlReader();
sgmlReader.DocType = "HTML";
sgmlReader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.All;
sgmlReader.CaseFolding = Sgml.CaseFolding.ToLower;

sgmlReader.InputStream = new StringReader(loadedFile);

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
doc.XmlResolver = null;
doc.Load(sgmlReader);
```

This code works fine for most cases, except on this site - [www.arrow.com](http://www.arrow.com/) (try to search something like OP295GS). I can get a table with result using the following XPath:

```
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode(".//*[@id='results-table']");
```

This gives me a node with several child nodes:

```
[0]         {Element, Name="thead"}  
[1]         {Element, Name="tbody"}  
[2]         {Element, Name="tbody"}  
FirstChild   {Element, Name="thead"}
```

Ok, let's try to get some child nodes using XPath. But this doesn't work:

```
var childNodes = node.SelectNodes("tbody");
//childnodes.Count = 0
```

This also:

```
var childNode = node.SelectSingleNode("thead");
// childNode = null
```

And even this:

```
var childNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(".//*[@id='results-table']/thead")
```

What can be wrong in Xpath queries?

---

I've just tried to parse that HTML page with *Html Agility Pack* and my XPath queries work good. But my application use XmlDocument inside,  *Html Agility Pack* doesn't suit me.

---

I even tried the following trick with *Html Agility Pack*, but Xpath queries doesn't work also:

```
//let's parse and convert HTML document using HTML Agility Pack and then load
//the result to XmlDocument
HtmlDocument xmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
xmlDocument.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
xmlDocument.Load(new StringReader(webPage));

XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(xmlDocument.DocumentNode.InnerHtml);
```

Perhaps, web page contains errors (not all tags are closed and so on), but in spite of this I can see child nodes (through Quick Watch in Visual Studio), but cannot access them through XPath.

---

My XPath queries works correctly in Firefox + FirePath + XPather plugins, but don't work in .net XmlDocument :(

Comment: +1 for a good question, and for parsing HTML with the Agility Pack and XML parsers rather than regex.

Comment: HTML Agility Pack is easy to use, but it has it's own data types, what can be a problem when integrating in an existing logic.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used SqmlReader, but every time I have seen this problem it has been due to namespaces.  A quick look at the HTML on www.arrow.com shows that this node has a namespace (note the xmlns:javaurlencoder):

```
<form name="CatSearchForm" method="post" action="http://components.arrow.com/part/search/OP295GS" xmlns:javaurlencoder="java.net.URLEncoder">
```

This code is how I loop through all nodes in a document to see which ones have namespaces and which don't.  If the node you are looking for or any of its parents have namespaces, you must create a `XmlNamespaceManager` and pass it along with your call to `SelectNodes()`.

This is kind of annoying, so another idea might be to strip all the xmlns: attributes out of the XML before loading it into a `XmlDocument`.  Then, you won't need to fool with `XmlNamespaceManager`!

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\temp\X.loadtest.xml");

Dictionary<string, string> namespaces = new Dictionary<string, string>();
XmlNodeList nlAllNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//*");
foreach (XmlNode n in nlAllNodes)
{
    if (n.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) continue;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(n.NamespaceURI) && !namespaces.ContainsKey(n.Name))
    {
        namespaces.Add(n.Name, n.NamespaceURI);
    }
}

// Inspect the namespaces dictionary to write the code below

XmlNamespaceManager nMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
// Sometimes this works
nMgr.AddNamespace("ns1", doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI); 
// You can make the first param whatever you want, it just must match in XPath queries
nMgr.AddNamespace("javaurlencoder", "java.net.URLEncoder"); 

XmlNodeList iter = doc.SelectNodes("//ns1:TestProfile", nMgr);
foreach (XmlNode n in iter)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest when I am trying to get information from a website I use regex. 
Ok Kore Nordmann (in his php blog) thinks, this is not good. But some of the comments tell differently.

http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0081_parse_html_extract_data_from_html.html

http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html

But it is in php, so sorry for this =) Hope it helps anyway.

Comment: There are some very good reasons not to try to parse (X)HTML with regex. For one thing, it's literally impossible to do it correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: In JDownloader in all the decrypter plugins we use regex too. 
I wrote a BrowserGame bot using regex, ok but anyway, this was the reason why they were able to detect the bot after some years. The installed a gap, and due to regex my bot did not understand, that the page has changed, but this could have been done by regex as well. I just forgot to ensure, to build in a "htmlstructure has not changed" mechanism to avoid beeing detected.

Comment: The previous version of my app used Regex inside. It was a nightmare (comparing to Xpath).